# Check if table exists in Unity Meta Catalog

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

So I am trying to build a weekly Data import to Unity Catalog in Databricks.
I use python.

There is no problem overwriting the table in case it exists:

```
%sql
Use catalog some_catalog

dfTarget                 #some pandas dataframe
df_sparkTarget=spark.createDataFrame(dfTarget)
df_sparkTarget.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(database+"."+table)
```

But before I ovverwrite anything I would like to check for the existence of this table:

```
if spark.catalog.tableExists( database+"."+table):
  print("Table exists")
else:
  print("Table does not exist")
```

This returns the following error

```
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public boolean org.apache.spark.sql.internal.CatalogImpl.tableExists(java.lang.String) is not whitelisted on class class org.apache.spark.sql.internal.CatalogImpl
```

Where can I whitelist this?
Maybe just for this one cluster and not for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I have found much the same for now until there is documented ways to do this I am using this. Catalog functionality only seems to work for the hivemetastore

```
def schema_exists(catalog:str, schema_name:str):
    query = spark.sql(f"""
            SELECT 1 
            FROM {catalog}.information_schema.schemata 
            WHERE schema_name = '{schema_name}' 
            LIMIT 1""")
    
    return query.count() > 0

def table_exists(catalog:str, schema:str, table_name:str):
    query = spark.sql(f"""
            SELECT 1 
            FROM {catalog}.information_schema.tables 
            WHERE table_name = '{table_name}' 
            AND table_schema='{schema}' LIMIT 1""",
        )
    return query.count() > 0

schema_exists("catalog_name","schema_name")
table_exists("catalog_name","schema_name", "table_name")
```

Comment: Another alternative is to use a Single User cluster rather than a Shared cluster, if possible.